# Observer checkout_submit_all_after not called on magento 2.3.3

Tags: event-observer, sales-order

This is my app/code/Nadine/Campaign/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="nadine_campaign_saa" instance="Nadine\Campaign\Observer\SubmitAllAfter"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

This is my observer (app/code/Nadine/Campaign/Observer/SubmitAllAfter.php)

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Nadine\Campaign\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;

class SubmitAllAfter implements ObserverInterface
{


    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $handle = fopen('/home/mytest/public_html/staging/var/logghetto.txt', 'a');
        fwrite($handle, "Start my observer SubmitAllAfter alle ore ".date("H:i:s"));
        fwrite($handle,"\n====\n");
        
        fclose($handle);
        die('test in progress');
    }
}
```

But, when I send an order, this observer don't works. On /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php I see that, with this code:

```
$this->eventManager->dispatch('checkout_submit_all_after', ['order' => $order, 'quote' => $quote]);
```

the event is correctly invoked.

Comment: It will work, if you change the area to `webapi_rest` as answered below.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

change the `events.xml` area from global to `webapi_rest`

use

`app/code/Nadine/Campaign/etc/webapi_rest/events.xml`

instead of

`app/code/Nadine/Campaign/etc/events.xml`

It will work

---

Better observe the event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`, in case if you want to observe the `store front order placement` and use `one page checkout`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="nadine_campaign_saa" instance="Nadine\Campaign\Observer\SubmitAllAfter"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

`Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success`

> $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
> '**checkout_onepage_controller_success_action**',
> [
> '**order_ids**' => [$session->getLastOrderId()],
> '**order**' => $session->getLastRealOrder()
> ]
> )

[Reference](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1581#issuecomment-126400100)

Comment: Hi there @Haijerome, why is it necessary to change the area to webapi? Some kind of bug or something?

Comment: Hi @DianaBotean , order placement is handled by `REST API (webapi)` so it can be observed only from `webapi` area. It's not a bug BTW. You can find more details about this in this thread https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1581#issuecomment-126400100

Comment: thanks! yeah, well coming from m1 development, clearly i still need to adjust to m2 :)

Comment: Yes totally agreed, M1 keeps it simple , whereas M2 keeps it much organized and structured. I'm still not feeling like home with M2 with some areas, though its nice to work with :-)